# Unable to match URL in URL.conf in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

What am I doing wrong ?

> My URL : http://localhost:8000/login/

The DEBUG log from Django :

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/login/
Using the URLconf defined in dealers.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^login|home/ ^login/$
^login|home/ ^home/$
^login|home/ ^home/dealer/(?P<dealer_id>\d+)/$
^admin/
The current URL, login/, didn't match any of these.
```

urls.py file :

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
  (r'^login|home/',include('dealerpanel.urls')),
  (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
)
```

dealerpanel/urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('dealerpanel.views',
  (r'^login/$','login'),
  (r'^home/$','home'),
  (r'^home/dealer/(?P<dealer_id>\d+)/$','details')
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
## urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  (r'',include('dealerpanel.urls')),
  (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
)
```

Change the prefix for including `dealerpanel.urls` to be the empty string. I think the way you have it structured it would actually be looking for a url like:

```
/login/login/
/login/home/
/home/login
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this to your `dealerpanel/urls.py` so that `http://localhost:8000/login/` will hit the view `dealerpanel.views.target_view`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('dealerpanel.views',
  ...
  (r'','target_view'),
)
```

This means the empty string after `login` (or `home`) will match the `target_view`